# Падает node.js в Heroku через некоторое время

Tags: node.js, heroku

Подскажите, что может быть, пожалуйста. Запускается, ~ час работает, затем отключается, из логов:

```
2016-08-18T08:04:12.604775+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down 
2016-08-18T08:04:15.386547+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-08-18T08:04:16.199809+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

index.js:

```
var TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
var token = '234735407:AAHBl05EUkVFEhJdkpWqfOuExwwrMcgvzfg';
var bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);

});

bot.on('message', function (msg) {
    var chatId = msg.chat.id;
    console.log(msg);
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Hello!", {caption: "I'm a bot!"});

});
```

Comment: а если автоматический перезапуск прописать в коде?

Comment: Если подскажешь как - буду благодарен.

Comment: Сервер то https, да?

Comment: @Suvitruf, да, https

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dyno типа `web` или пары `worker`+`web` **Heroku** [**выключает**, если к ним нет запросов за последние полчаса](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours) на бесплатном тарифе.

...и поднимает новые dyno, когда приходит запрос, что занимает какое-то время, но позволяет Heroku не расходовать ресурсы на брошенные "игрушечные" проекты вообще.

Поскольку боты Telegram при использовании обычного API ходят за сообщениями сами, сообщение боту в Telegram не приведёт к его пробуждению. Нужен *входящий* запрос, тогда как обращения к API *исходящие*.

Вероятно, если изменить тип dyno с `web` на `worker` (в `Procfile`), не добавляя `web`, он не будет засыпать. Но и обслуживать входящие HTTP-запросы не сможет, так что Express можно будет выкинуть. Боту это без надобности всё равно.

А лучше перейти на вебхуки. Тогда подача данных от Telegram будет происходить через *входящие* HTTP-запросы, что *будет* будить бота.

---

Поскольку Heroku в месяц выделяет всего 550 бесплатных машино-часов на аккаунт (а `31 * 24 = 744`), беспрерывно работающий бот **успеет** употребить все, и ощутимый промежуток времени будет под снотворным (его будет не разбудить). Можно расширить этот лимит до 1000 (на 450 часов), привязав банковскую карточку. Тогда спать ему будет уже необязательно, если нет других (существенных) потребителей машино-часов на этом же аккаунте.

---

Встречается информация, что в сутки приложение **обязано** спать как минимум 6 часов (`(24 - 6) * 31 = 558`). Это *неактуально*. Heroku [в блоге](https://blog.heroku.com/announcing_heroku_free_ssl_beta_and_flexible_dyno_hours#flexible-free-dyno-hours) (спасибо за наводку [Alex78191](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/182273/alex78191)) явно указывает на возможность держать чатбота 24/7 на бесплатном аккаунте.

Comment: Если бы он поднимал через некоторое время,то еще ладно, а так пока не сделаешь **heroku ps:scale web=0 и heroku ps:scale web=1** ничего не оживет.

Comment: в том то и дело, что не оживает.. отправляю "боту" сообщения - молчит. Ответит только после перезапуска.

Comment: нет, отправлял с интервалом час, 5 минут, минута, не отвечает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44150/discussion-between-batman-and-d-side).

Comment: После редактирования Procfile на worker: node index.js $PORT проблема решилась, спасибо.

Comment: Процессы все равно стопнулись, если обновить страницу MY-APP.herokuapp.com, то бот "оживает", можно как-то дергать эту страницу ботом? Или нужно на вэбхуки переходить может?

Comment: @batman По идее, на MY-APP.herokuapp.com отвечать должно быть некому. Посмотрите в настройках, у вас там web dyno остался что ли?

Comment: @batman похоже, что да, надо переходить на вебхуки, т. к. в случае с ними запрос совершают серверы Телеграма, а приложение отвечает на них запросом (?!) к API ботов. Вот такая петрушка, если я всё правильно понял.

Comment: ну да, получается "телеграм" будет будить бота, Procfile оставил worker

Comment: Начиная с [1 июня 2016 г.](https://blog.heroku.com/announcing_heroku_free_ssl_beta_and_flexible_dyno_hours) приложение не обязано спать 6 часов в сутки. Если добавить банковскую карту, то будет доступно 1000 часов на аккаунт.

Comment: @Alex78191 спасибо, переработал ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Завершение SSL сессии происходит на лод балансере Heroku.

Эта проблема описана [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185074/heroku-nodejs-http-to-https-ssl-forced-redirect/23894573#23894573), но я с Heroku никогда не работал, так что не могу перевести без знания вопроса ответ.

Можете посмотреть на [этот](https://github.com/florianheinemann/express-sslify) модуль.

Comment: Может, знаешь какие альтернативы?